# Get array values between two position

Tags: php

I have for example array:

```
$list = array(40, 22, 60, 50);
```

and:

```
$start = 40;
$end = 60;
```

I would like get values between $start and $end (can be with $start and $end). For this example I would like receive:

```
array(40, 22, 60);
```

If:

```
$start = 22;
$end = 60;
```

Then i would like receive:

```
array(22, 60);
```

AND IF:

```
$list = array(40, 22, 60, 50, 100, 200, 70);
```

and:

```
$start = 22;
$end = 200;
```

I would like receive:
    array(22, 60, 50, 100, 200);

How can I make it?

Comment: By iterating through your array and deciding for each value if it is within the interval.

Comment: Will the `$start` and `$end` values always be in the array?

Comment: See [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the array, but there's another way:

```
$list = array(40, 22, 60, 50, 100, 200, 70);
$start = 22;
$end = 200;

$start_position = array_search($start, $list);
$end_position = array_search($end, $list);
$values = array_slice($list, $start_position, $end_position - $start_position + 1);
```